# java external threads (outside the class file it's used)

Tags: java, multithreading, class, external, internal

The question is, is it possible to have an external thread or do they have to be internal to the class they run in. If so could someone show me how. (external thread)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Remember before Java 1.4 (I believe), ALL Java classes were required to be in there own files

Comment: I really cannot understand some downvotes. Is it because the OP doesn't know the correct, or most commonly used, terms? Or is it because he didn't look for some information, on a topic in which *he doesn't know the terms to look for*? Is it *really that hard* to understand what is being asked here? Come on. Upvoted to compensate for those unexplained downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *thread*, or, more precisely, a *thread of execution* is something, and the class `Thread` is something closely related but different, and it seems that you are mixing up these two concepts.

You can think of a *thread of execution* as a machine that will execute operations sequentially. One way to define and run such a machine is to write a class `MyClass` with a `main()` method and call `java MyClass`.

Another way is to create a new instance of the `Thread` class and call its method `start()`. This will create a new *thread of execution* which will run the code that is in the `run()` method of the `Thread` class, which does nothing by default. For this to be useful, you usually override the `run` method, which is what I think you are calling *a thread internal to the class...*:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
  @Override public void run() {
    // ... some code ...
  }
}
// ...
  final Thread t = new MyThread();
  t.start();
```

In this example, after the `run()` method of the class `MyThread` returns, the *thread of execution* associated to that instance of `MyThread` will terminate (just like when your single-threaded program returns from -- or reaches the end of -- your `main()` method).

Another possibility is to pass the `Thread` an instance of a `Runnable`. Then you separate the 2 concepts: the *thread of execution*, which is represented by an instance of `Thread`, will execute the code in the instance of `Runnable`:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  @Override public void run {
    // this code will get executed by a thread
  }
}
  // ...
  final MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
  final Thread t = new Thread(t);
  t.start();
```

This maybe closer to what you call an *external thread*, although this nomenclature is highly unconventional.

So, you see that there are 2 different, but closely related, concepts here.

Now, in Java you have a way to create a *thread of execution* that will be waiting for you to give it some code to execute. After it is created, it goes to a *pool*, and sits there. You *submit* some code for it to run, and when it finishes, instead of terminating, the thread of execution keeps alive and goes back to that *pool*. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

To do it, you usually use an `ExecutorService`. For example:

```
class MyMainClass {
  private static final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
  public static void main(String... args) {
    es.submit(new MyRunnable());
    es.submit(new MyRunnable());
    es.submit(new MyRunnable());
    es.submit(new MyRunnable());
    es.submit(new MyRunnable());
  }
}
```

In this example, the *pool* contains 10 threads of execution. You can submit any amount of instances of `Runnable` for it, and it will distribute them among the 10 threads. Each call to `submit(...)` on the `ExecutorService` returns an instance of `Future`, which you can use to know if the *thread of execution* that was running your `Runnable` did already finish, and if it finished successfully or due to an uncaught exception.

I suggest that you take a look at the javadocs for all the classes I mentioned here: `Thread`, `Runnable`, `ExecutorService`, `Executors` and `Future`. There's a lot to learn from that documentation!

As a final note, remember that if you start playing with threads and `ExecutorService`s, you will get all kinds of headache. You will have to think about situations in which the execution cannot proceed (deadlocks, livelocks), about operations that need to be atomic (ie, incrementing a variable from different threads), memory visibility (ie, if you change the value of a field without "taking care", it can happen that other threads will never notice the change to that field!). Also remember that the JVM won't die until every last non-daemon thread finishes; in other words, the example above will never terminate, even if all the submitted `Runnable`s finish, because the *threads of execution* in the `ExecutorService` are still alive!

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed to get a globally running thread working.